# Trying to understand what a Method is, how can it be 'part of a class'?

Tags: ruby, methods

I've done some work with functions in Javascript, and thought that a Method was the Ruby name for the same. I recently did a technical interview and the interviewer was trying to help me debug by explaining how Methods were part of a class, and that it's an OOP thing.

I can't spot a functional difference between a Method and an equivalent Function, so I don't see what classes have to do with it.

**Can you explain the whole 'Methods are part of a class' thing and why it matters? How can a Method be part of a class? Class as in an integer or a string?**

The interviewer believed it would help, but it seems like a tiny technicality more than something useful.

Comment: Well, ruby doesn't have functions. Only methods. And they all belong to some class.

Comment: "and why it matters" - classes are "data + behaviour". Methods are the behaviour part. Without them, classes become just dumb structs and are much less useful (from OOP perspective anyway)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Doesnt ruby lambdas kind of a functions in js?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky: similar, but not quite the same. 1) They are fully-fledged objects themselves and because of that 2) they are not directly invocable (you can't do `my_lambda()`, only `my_lambda.call` or `my_lambda.()` or one of 50 other ways)

Comment: _"How can a Method be part of a class?"_ – by definition, that's essentially what makes it a method.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Methods belong to modules (of which classes are a specialization).

Comment: @JörgWMittag: ruby's implementation details. :)

Answer (score 3):

> Can you explain the whole 'Methods are part of a class' thing and why it matters? How can a Method be part of a class? Class as in an integer or a string?

Let's say you have two classes, Apple and Cake. Let's assume that when you sell an apple, it has a tax rate of 10%, and cake 20%. By splitting the methods into individual classes, we can define a different method for 'price_with_tax' to each class:

```
class Apple < ApplicationRecord
  def price_with_tax
    self.price * 1.1
  end
end

class Cake < ApplicationRecord
  def price_with_tax
    self.price * 1.2
  end
end
```

In javascript we wouldn't be able to do this, and would need to have 2 methods, 'add 10% tax' and 'add 20% tax'. By structuring the methods as we have, we're able to do:

```
apple = Apple.find(1)
cake = Cake.find(1)
cake.price_with_tax
apple.price_with_tax
```

Comment: I think I get it, part of the problem was my understanding of what a class was.
So is it that a Method requires a class, that is to say some information that can be contained within or without of the Method to work, and that the information is considered an object in itself?

Comment: I think your confusions comes from using functions in JS which don't require a class. You can call any function you've defined from anywhere in your code. Class orientated design is pretty much the opposite of this - you want the same method (function name) to do different things to different classes. A ruby method has to operate on a class (and where it looks like you aren't calling it on a class it's in fact happening without you realising - like when you call a method in a controller, the method is called on an instance of that controller class)

Answer (score 2):

Methods are generally something that a class can do,
class MailClient(for example) might have methods such as sendMail, getMail, forwardMail, etc. In OOP, methods should for the most part be something that a class can do.

```
    MailClient.getMail();
```

The above code can be conceptualized as telling the class to invoke its getMail() behavior.

You may think of this in real-life terms such as:

`Dog.bark();`

Objects have behavior and attributes, the behaviors are the methods.

Comment: So my understanding now is that you can create some information as a class, and then apply a Method to it. Does a Method always require a class, and would you say that Methods are built around classes?

Comment: Methods/Functions in JavaScript do not require a class, although it helps greatly with code organization, and can improve readability by logically grouping a class's specific functions together.

I would suggest reading more on JavaScript classes as they work differently than some OOP languages today.

A lot of it boils down to personal preference, however, following known JavaScript coding conventions will make your code more easily understandable by a wider array of audiences.

Answer (score 0):

In OOP:

Class is like a blueprint/template. It has properties, methods etc. An object can be created with it. So an object can call method in class.
Usually a method is created to perform an operation.

Example:

```
// a demo class
public class Animal{
    // a method
    public void sound(){
        // do something...
    }

    // main class, we create an object and call sound() method
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Animal dog = new Animal();     // create an object so that we can use the method
        dog.sound();    // method call
    }
}
```